# How can I speed up this bit of code (loop/lists/tuple optimization)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization

I repeat the following idiom again and again. I read from a large file (sometimes, up to 1.2 million records!) and store the output into an SQLite databse. Putting stuff into the SQLite DB seems to be fairly fast.

```
def readerFunction(recordSize, recordFormat, connection, outputDirectory, outputFile, numObjects):

    insertString = "insert into NODE_DISP_INFO(node, analysis, timeStep, H1_translation, H2_translation, V_translation, H1_rotation, H2_rotation, V_rotation) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 

    analysisNumber = int(outputPath[-3:])

    outputFileObject = open(os.path.join(outputDirectory, outputFile), "rb")
    outputFileObject, numberOfRecordsInFileObject = determineNumberOfRecordsInFileObjectGivenRecordSize(recordSize, outputFileObject)

    numberOfRecordsPerObject = (numberOfRecordsInFileObject//numberOfObjects)

    loop1StartTime = time.time()
    for i in range(numberOfRecordsPerObject ):  
        processedRecords = []

        loop2StartTime = time.time()

        for j in range(numberOfObjects):
            fout = outputFileObject .read(recordSize)

            processedRecords.append(tuple([j+1, analysisNumber, i] + [x for x in list(struct.unpack(recordFormat, fout))]))

        loop2EndTime = time.time()
        print "Time taken to finish loop2: {}".format(loop2EndTime-loop2StartTime)  

        dbInsertStartTime = time.time()
        connection.executemany(insertString, processedRecords)
        dbInsertEndTime = time.time()

    loop1EndTime = time.time()
    print "Time taken to finish loop1: {}".format(loop1EndTime-loop1StartTime)

    outputFileObject.close()
    print "Finished reading output file for analysis {}...".format(analysisNumber)
```

When I run the code, it seems that "loop 2" and "inserting into the database" is where most execution time is spent. Average "loop 2" time is **0.003s**, but it is run up to **50,000** times, in some analyses. The time spent putting stuff into the database is about the same: **0.004s**. Currently, I am inserting into the database every time after loop2 finishes so that I don't have to deal with running out RAM.

What could I do to speed up "loop 2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily an I/O issue.

```
for j in range(numberOfObjects):
    fout = outputFileObject .read(recordSize)
```

You are spending most of your time reading teeny incremental bits of your file (i.e. one record at a time), then using `struct` to unpack those individual records.  This is slow.  Instead, grab that *whole* chunk of the file that you want all at once, then let `struct.unpack` churn through it at C speed.

You will need to do a little bit of math to figure out how many bytes to `read`, and alter your `recordFormat` format string to tell `struct` how to unpack the whole thing.  There is not quite enough info in your example for me to tell you more precisely how you should do that.

I also have to point out that this:

```
tuple([j+1, analysisNumber, i] + [x for x in list(struct.unpack(recordFormat, fout))])
```

is *far* more sanely written as this:

```
(j+1, analysisNumber, i) + struct.unpack(recordFormat, fout)
```

...but you will need to refactor that line if you follow my above advice to remove the loop entirely.  (you can use `zip` and `enumerate` to prepend that data onto each struct member after the whole thing is unpacked)

---

**edit:** example.  I packed 1M unsigned ints into a file.  `yours()` is your approach, `mine()` is mine.

```
def yours():
     res = []
     with open('packed', 'rb') as f:
         while True:
             b = f.read(4)
             if not b:
                 break
             res.append(struct.unpack('I',b))
     return res

def mine():
     with open('packed', 'rb') as f:
         return struct.unpack('1000000I',f.read())
```

Timings:

```
%timeit yours()
1 loops, best of 3: 388 ms per loop

%timeit mine()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.14 ms per loop
```

So, about 2 orders of magnitude difference.

Comment: *facepalm* I always thought for some reason that tuples couldn't be updated like that...my god...

Comment: Well, they can't be *updated* per se (they're immutable and all), but `tuple1 + tuple2` gives you a new (third) tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I think the using of mmap module to work with memory mapped file 
might help you to save time twice.  I found that too small or 
very large chunk does not save much, but you can try to see optimal size.

```
import mmap

def binFileRead(chunk):   # the reading of binary file length size
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        for n in range(int(length/chunk)):
            dd=f.read(chunk) 

def mapFileRead(chunk):  # the reading of memory mapped file length size
    with open(filename, "r+b") as f:
        mapf = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)  
        for n in range(int(length/chunk)):
            offset=n*chunk
            dd=mapf[offset:offset+chunk]
          #  dd=mapf.read(chunk)
        mapf.close()
```

I timed both functions:

```
timeit("mapFileRead({})".format(n),"from __main__ import mapFileRead", number=1))
timeit("binFileRead({})".format(n),"from __main__ import binFileRead", number=1))

chunk=4096: 
  mapFileRead 0.00837285185687 
  binFileRead 0.0148429479166
```

edited: 
I think, an index access to file while reading is allowed to use threads with parallel reading of several records. I can write an example if you interested.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in loop 2 I see is mis-use of list comprehension.

Dont use `[x for x in list]` on a list type object. Because you are doing nu-necessary iteration here. It can be written just as `list`

So you should write something like this,

```
processedRecords.append(
    tuple([j+1, analysisNumber, i] + list(struct.unpack(recordFormat, fout))))
```